# update autoconf to at least 2.6

Tags: centos, autoconf

I have autoconf 2.59 on CentOS 5.5 and need to upgrade to autoconf 2.6.
What is the best approach for this? 
I tried yum update autoconf but theres no luck

Comment: Install autoconf from source in your home directory.

Comment: s/2.6/2.60/g   (Version 2.6 was released in 1995 and version 2.60 in 2006)

Comment: Here is one ... http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/r/ro/roblinux/64-32_pkg/dev/x86_64/autoconf-2.65-1rt.x86_64.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd get it from RPMForge or ATrpms, but I don't see that they have it either.  Some other CentOS 3rd party repository might.  Download [GNU Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and build it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the RPM here:
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15945938/dir/redhat_el_5/com/autoconf26x-2.63-4.ius.el5.noarch.rpm.html

And install it with YUM:

```
yum install something.i586.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/

download binary and install