# why i failed to build autoconf with autoconf2.6x, its version is newer  than 2.6 anyhow

Tags: linux, build, centos, autoconf, automake

my system is centos based.

the reason i try to build autoconf is that someone told me i can try to build it in order to solve the other problem, you may find the motivation with this link [why autogen.sh failed even with the correct autoconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136934/why-autogen-sh-failed-even-with-the-correct-autoconf#comment16480229_12136934)

```
[mirror@home auto]$ cd autoconf/
[mirror@home autoconf]$ ls
AUTHORS    cfg.mk       ChangeLog.3        COPYINGv3    lib          man           README-hacking
bin        ChangeLog.0  configure.ac       doc          m4           NEWS          tests
BUGS       ChangeLog.1  COPYING            GNUmakefile  maint.mk     README        THANKS
build-aux  ChangeLog.2  COPYING.EXCEPTION  HACKING      Makefile.am  README-alpha  TODO
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoreconf -iv
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
configure.ac:20: error: Autoconf version 2.60 or higher is required
configure.ac:20: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 63
```

//  i have autoreconf2.6x on my system, its version si higher than 2.6, but still failed to build, why?

```
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autore
autoreconf      autoreconf2.59  autoreconf2.6x  autorespond
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autore
autoreconf      autoreconf2.59  autoreconf2.6x  autorespond
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoreconf2.6x -iv


[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoconf2.6x --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.63
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

still failed to build autoconf, what i should do in order to build it?

```
[mirror@home autoconf]$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoconf
configure.ac:29: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:117: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_GNU_M4
configure.ac:124: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_MISSING_PROG
configure.ac:187: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_LISPDIR
configure.ac:201: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_MAKE_CASE_SENSITIVE
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoconf2.
autoconf2.59  autoconf2.6x
[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoconf2.6x

[mirror@home autoconf]$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/ins/ins_auto


[mirror@home autoconf]$ autoreconf2.6x
configure.ac:20: error: Autoconf version 2.60 or higher is required
configure.ac:20: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 63
autoreconf2.6x: aclocal failed with exit status: 63
```

Comment: check out http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/autofailure.xml

Comment: Why are you running autoreconf?  I presume the `cd autoconf` indicates that you are in an unpacked tarball of autoconf.  Just run the configure script.  You are running into the same problem here as before; your system is set up so that autoreconf is finding and running the old autoconf.

Comment: @WilliamPursell i have replied with more details above, still failed...

Comment: Are you trying to build from the autoconf git repository, or from a tarball?  You will find it easier to build from a tarball.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, from autoconf git repo, then i would checkout some tags:)

Comment: So what does `autom4te --version` prints?

Comment: @adl autom4te (GNU Autoconf) 2.59

Comment: So you have two versions of autoconf installed, and when `aclocal` runs `autom4te`, this launches the old one.  Do you have a `autom4te-2.6x` in your path?  If so, set `export AUTOM4TE=autom4te-2.6x` before running `autoreconf-2.64`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two versions of autoconf installed, and when `aclocal` runs `autom4te`, this launches the old one. Do you have a `autom4te-2.6x` in your path? If so, set `export AUTOM4TE=autom4te2.6x` before running `autoreconf-2.64`.

Comment: Some configure script uses the environment M4 so you might want to try add both